# How is this Code Refactor Not Equivalent?

Tags: javascript, passport.js, mern, passport-local

I'm just not seeing how this refactored code is not equivalent. The former works as expected, the latter returns 404.

Login is successful with:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  var userInfo = { username: req.user.username };
  res.send(userInfo);
});
```

The error `xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/user/login/ 404 (Not Found)` is thrown with:

```
const authController = require('./controllers/authController');
    
router.post('/login', authController.login);
```

where `authController` is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/User');
const passport = require('../passport');

exports.login = passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  var userInfo = { username: req.user.username };
  res.send(userInfo);
}
```

The request headers are exactly the same in both cases.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to learn what the comma operator does. You can not just replace two arguments with one.

Comment: Your first snippet is giving post three arguments.  Your refactored code is giving two.

Comment: I am surprised code is not giving you the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('` Guessing you need to check the server logs.

Comment: Thanks y'all. Time to back away from the screen for the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to replace two arguments with one. The comma operator does not work like that. You would need to expose two exports.

```
const authController = require('./controllers/authController');
router.post('/login', authController.authLocal, authController.login);
```

and your exports would be

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/User');
const passport = require('../passport');

exports.authLocal = passport.authenticate('local');
exports.login = (req, res) => {
  var userInfo = { username: req.user.username };
  res.send(userInfo);
}
```